# How to inherit custom UITableViewCell to just change action methods

Tags: ios, swift, oop

In my app i have custom UITableViewCell A who is owner of the xib file A. Now i need to use all of the functionality of A but need to change buttons action. Is there any way to do this by inheriting A to a new class B.

Comment: You can make a class `B` that inherits from `A`, but you will need to duplicate the xib file and change the class to `B` - Isn't there some way you can have the action performed by a delegate or by passing a closure?  Provide more information.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes i can do some delegation or closure to accomplish this though need to create new xib. is there any way to change xib owner dynamically?

Comment: No, the nib owner is in the file and the file is read-only at run time

Comment: How do you instantiate & load *A who is owner of the xib file A*?

Comment: @Asperi yes class A is the owner of xib, and i am using dequeReusableCell to get instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach

```
class ACell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
        // do action A
    }
}

class BCell: ACell {
    @IBAction override func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
        // do action B
    }
}


// demo parent controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bCell = BCell()   // keep reference to cell

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // assuming A (substitute real name below) xib is located in
        // application main bundle, load it as linked to BCell instance
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("A_Xib_Name", owner: bCell)
    }
}
```